threejs transform control change the yellow material on hover
I have this transform control and I want to change its yellow material that comes as default when hovering the mouse over it:

I took a look at the source code and found the matYellow variable but there are no signs where it was used. In case I opt to implement a custom raycast, how do I disable the hover effect that comes as default?
regards!
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/TransformControls.js#L845
